# En la creación de un producto, poder actualizarlo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

estoy teniendo un lio con buscarle la logica a esto.

Tengo una vista donde tengo varios campos para crear un producto. Como son productos con variaciones, se me complica un poco más, así que paso a detallaros los pasos que sigo.

1)Relleno el nombre del producto
2)Relleno la descripción
4)Tengo un desplegable con los atributos que puedo añadir.
5)Cuando añado el atributo me sale un multiselect, con los posibles variaciones que puedo añadirle.
6)Cuando doy a guardar variaciones, lo hago con una petición AJAX donde mando un arreglo de todas las variaciones en JSON, y mando el nombre y descripción del producto.

**Está es mu función para cuando apreto a guardar las variaciones**

```
$("#guarTT").click(() => {
        var selects = $(".variaciones").toArray();
        var tipos = selects.map((item) => {
        return { id: $(item).attr("id"), variaciones: $(item).val() || [] };
        });
        //console.log(tipos);
        // Generamos las permutaciones
        var array = obtenerCombinaciones(tipos);
        var producto = $('#nombre').val();
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('descripcion');
        var descripcion = ed.getContent();

        let url = 'add-producto/variaciones/producto';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {'array': JSON.stringify(array), 
                   'Producto': producto,
                   'Descripcion': descripcion },     
            success: function(data){
                if( !data.success ){
                    toastr.success( "Combinaciones completadas", "Perfecto!");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                toastr.success( "Revisa las combinaciones", "Algo salio mal!");
            }
         });
        console.log(array);
    });
```

Luego una vez en el controlador.

```
public function variacionesProducto(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($_POST['array']);

        $productoAdd = new Product;
        $productoAdd->name = $request->input('Producto');
        $productoAdd->descripcion = $request->input('Descripcion');
        $productoAdd->estado = "3";
        $productoAdd->save();

        $idProductoRecienGuardada = $productoAdd->id;

        foreach($data as $item){
            $variaciones = new Variation;
            $variaciones->product_id = $idProductoRecienGuardada;
            $variaciones->variant = $item->tipoId;
            $variaciones->valor = $item->variacion;
            
            $variaciones->save();
        } 

        $variaciones = Variation::where('product_id', $idProductoRecienGuardada)->get();
        $producto = Product::findOrFail($idProductoRecienGuardada);

        
        return with(["variaciones" => $variaciones, "producto" => $producto]);
    }
```

Lo que hago es agregar un nuevo producto con su nombre y descripción. Después hago un foreach, para guardar todas las filas que vienen en el arreglo.
Todo esto me funciona perfecto, pero tengo varias dudas.

1)Como estoy en la vista de creación del producto, y la petición es por AJAX y la página no se actualiza, en el caso de que cambie de opinión y modifique las variaciones o bien ya guarde del todo el producto, siempre me genera uno nuevo como es normal, pero necesito que edite el que ya he mandado la primera vez. No se si se puede pasar algún parametro para decirle que id de producto estoy añadiendo.
2)Una vez que me llega la respuesta del JSON con la variaciones;

```
{variaciones: Array(4), producto: {…}}
producto:
created_at: "2020-08-28 23:16:16"
descripcion: "<p>Descripci&oacute;n camiseta Fire</p>"
estado: 3
id: 22
name: "Camiseta fire"
updated_at: "2020-08-28 23:16:16"
__proto__: Object
variaciones: Array(4)
0: {id: 55, product_id: 22, variant: "genero", valor: "mujer", precio: null, …}
1: {id: 56, product_id: 22, variant: "colores", valor: "negro", precio: null, …}
2: {id: 57, product_id: 22, variant: "colores", valor: "rojo", precio: null, …}
3: {id: 58, product_id: 22, variant: "colores", valor: "blanco", precio: null, …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
__
```

¿Como genero las filas en el CRUD, para poder terminar de rellenar las variaciones del producto?. Llevo toda la semana con esto y he probado de distintos modos, pero ya no se si estoy haciendo lo correcto.

Comment: En php, al recibir la petición para crear el elemento puedes devolver el elemento creado, o al menos su id. De esa manera luego cuando cambias algo y lo envías, puedes adjuntar la ID recibida. En php puedes comprobar si la petición que recibes trae una ID, si existe la ID es una actualización, si no, es para crear un elemento nuevo. Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Hola @Benito-B en la petición por ajax me traigo la id del producto, pero no se como utilizarla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras la idea de @Benito-B lo he realizado del siguiente modo:

Como en la petición AJAX me traigo la Id del producto, la inserto con el response de AJAX en un `input hidden`.

```
$("#respuesta").val(data.producto.id)
<input type="hidden" id="respuesta" name="respuesta" value="">
```

Luego en el controlador confirmo si viene esa ID o no:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['array']);

        if($request->input('ID') == "") {
            $productoAdd = new Product;
            $productoAdd->name = $request->input('Producto');
            $productoAdd->descripcion = $request->input('Descripcion');
            $productoAdd->estado = "3";
            $productoAdd->save();

            $idProductoRecienGuardada = $productoAdd->id;

            foreach($data as $item){
                $variaciones = new Variation;
                $variaciones->product_id = $idProductoRecienGuardada;
                $variaciones->variant = $item->tipoId;
                $variaciones->valor = $item->variacion;
                
                $variaciones->save();
            } 

            $variaciones = Variation::where('product_id', $idProductoRecienGuardada)->get();
            $producto = Product::findOrFail($idProductoRecienGuardada);
    
            return with(["variaciones" => $variaciones, "producto" => $producto]);

        }else{
            
            $actProducto = Product::findOrFail($request->input('ID'));
            $actProducto->name = $request->input('Producto');
            $actProducto->descripcion = $request->input('Descripcion');
            $actProducto->estado = "3";
            $actProducto->save();

            $idProductoRecienGuardada = $actProducto->id;

            $deleteVariation = Variation::where('product_id', $request->input('ID'));
            $deleteVariation->delete();

            foreach($data as $item){
                $editVariaciones = new Variation;
                $editVariaciones->product_id = $idProductoRecienGuardada;
                $editVariaciones->variant = $item->tipoId;
                $editVariaciones->valor = $item->variacion;
                
                $editVariaciones->save();
            } 
            
            $variaciones = Variation::where('product_id', $idProductoRecienGuardada)->get();
            $producto = Product::findOrFail($idProductoRecienGuardada);
    
            return with(["variaciones" => $variaciones, "producto" => $producto]);
        }
```

Si por post la ID viene vacia, creo un nuevo producto y sus variaciones, si por lo contrario si que viene, edito el producto, borro todas las variaciones con esa ID y las vuelvo a crear.

No se si hay forma más corta de hacerlo o bien más limpia, y mi pregunta es, cuando de a guardar el producto, tendre que crear una nueva URL y un nuevo function en el controlador haciendo las mismas comprobaciones??